# Extracting numbers from text in coldfusion

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I have the following text:
"my brother drunk 7 cups of coffee and then printed his homework in A4 paper. He then drove down the I-90 highway."

I want to extract only the numbers of the text (in this example 7,4,90). How can I do this with coldfusion?

I suspect the REMatch function must be used but I am not good with regular expressions, I appreciate everyone's help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just use rematch and this will return array of match numbers.

```
<cfset str = "my brother drunk 7 cups of coffee and then printed his homework in A4 paper. He then drove down the I-90 highway">
<cfset arrSearch = rematch("[\d]+",str)>
<cfdump var="#arrSearch#">
```